# Metric topology on closed set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, definition

I had a question on the following portion of lecture notes :

> Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Then for any $\delta > 0$, we define
> the open ball to be $B(x, \delta) := \{y \in X : d(x, y) < \delta\}$.
>
> One way to define open sets of a metric space, i.e. to dene the
> metric topology is to then just declare a set $U$ open if around any
> point $x \in U$, we can find an open ball $B(x,\delta) \subseteq U$:
>
> Lemma 2.4 (Metric topology). Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Define a
> set of subsets $τ_d$ as follows: we declare $U \subseteq X$ to be open
> (this is, we set $U$ to be in $τ_d$), if for every $x \in U$, we can
> find some $\delta > 0$ such that $B(x, \delta) \subseteq U$. Then
> $τ_d$ is a topology and is called the metric topology.

A topology on $X$ needs to contain X. What if the metric space is "closed" ? For example if $X=[0,1]$ and the usual distance on real numbers (absolute value), then for $U=X$ and $x=0$ we will not be able to find a $\delta > 0$ such that $B(x, \delta) \subseteq X$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of subspace metric space?

Comment: @ShreyaChauhan not yet :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main point is that in the definition of $B(x, \delta)$, you consider only points inside $X$. So for $X = [0,1]$, $B(0, \delta) = [0, \delta)$.

Comment: In fact, I noticed that this was the precise notion that was different from the definition of an open ball in $\mathbb R^n$ but I was not sure. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

*Every* topological space (and, in particular, every metric space) is a closed subset of itself. And it is also an open subset of itself.

Besides,$$B(x,\delta)=\{y\in X\mid d(y,x)<\delta\}$$and so *by definition* we always have $B(x,\delta)\subset X$.